# Netbeans 7.3 smarty in <script> tag

Tags: php, netbeans, kendo-ui, smarty, netbeans-7.3

I want to use netbeans ide 7.3 for my project, but if i put some smarty tags/variables into  tags, netbeans always highlighting as syntax error. How can i fix it? I cannot find any patch for this problem. In netbeans 7.2 the problem doesn't occur.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your code there is some error as I see:

you are using: `<div class="class1" class="class2">`

this will not support to class in a tag.

Use this code:
`<div class="class1 class2">`

If you want to use more than one class in a tag.

Comment: thx, but the problem is still persist, because of smarty... 
http://i.imgur.com/nAxBo3d.png

Comment: try to use the div tag outside of the script tag.

Comment: No, exactly what would be the point, div in script tag, with smarty (it's a KendoUI template snippet)

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 7.3 brought a new JavaScript editor, thus the difference from 7.2. This issue should be already fixed and it will be part of upcoming patch.